# Variating view controller based on global variable

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm currently developing app, that has signing process involved. It is tab-bar app, but for simplicity I'll use example with only 2 tabs. Home and Settings.

In home, user is presented his home screen with various photos and last messages. 
However, when user is not logged in, there is default anonymous view.

My question is, how do you guys work with one view controller and two different complex views. Home view controller is default after starting app. I'm using storyboards, so only one viewcontroller can be HomeViewController.(obviously :))

I know about possibility of doing multiple UIViews on one view controller and hiding/showing those views based on global variable (NSUserDefaults). Problem is, that both views have alot of outlets. (Scrollviews, tableviews etc). So for one, it would be hardcore to programm all of these outlets on UIView and there would be alot of redundancy. (Logged in user would log in, but data for all UIViews- that including view for unregistered user would have to be downloaded).

It would be easier just to create two view controllers and present one, based on if user is logged in or not.(just check NSUserDefaults dictionary in appdelegate's applicationdidfinishloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement so that `HomeViewController` is a controller that controls many view controllers. Same as how `UINavigationController` and `UITabViewController` controls many `viewControllers` and which `viewController` is visible.

Your HomeViewController would look something like this:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *authenticatedVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *anonymousVC;

- (void)showAuthenticatedView;
- (void)showAnonymousView;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // init your VCs
    self.authenticatedVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.anonymousVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    // show your initial VC (assuming anonymousView is you default)
    [self.view addSubview:self.authenticatedVC.view];
}

- (void)showAuthenticatedView
{
    // remove current view
    [self.authenticatedVC.view removeFromSuperView];

    // display authenticatedView
    [self.view addSubview:self.authenticatedVC.view];
}

- (void)showAnonymousView
{
    // remove current view
    [self.authenticatedVC.view removeFromSuperView];

    // display showAnonymousView
    [self.view addSubview:self.anonymousVC.view];
}

@end
```

** update:
This is a link from the ios dev lib about creating custom container view controllers: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: Hmm, I'm hearing about this concept first time... :) How would I do that? :) ... I mean, yes I know that I can do it in viewWillAppear method of HomeViewController (by presenting another controller), but then, navigation stack (i've got nav controllers in all of my tabs) would get messed up. But I'm probably not getting what you mean :)

Comment: i have updated my answer. I just wrote the code, never tested.

Comment: Thx for update calampunay... I'm away from my mac, so I'll test it tomorrow. Upvoting for now, looks good :)

Comment: Hey calampunay.. is there any way to do this with storyboards? I mean I have a lot of outlets on auth/anon view controllers and I would like to "design" them in storyboard enviroment rather than code it all the way :) I tried to do it similar to your way, where I created and named controllers in storyboard, but then, they are not attached to nav controller so I get an exception when I try to make segue from anon view to another controller.. I know that this is probably hard to do using Storyboard, thats why I ask :)

Comment: Yes. It is possible to do it using storyboards. You can create viewcontrollers in storyboard for auth & anon. You can also create custom segues. [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html)

Comment: I just read about this yesterday. I guess this is the standard for creating container view controllers. [io dev lib](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Comment: Hmm it is surely interesting.. However, when you have stand-alone view controller with lets say uibutton, that has push segue as action, it will crash, when you load view (with that button) to your "home" controller. (Because that standalone vc is not connected to nav controller, so navigation can't be made). I'm talking about using it with storyboards of course. I just created different views on same controller, and I'm adding/removing them accordingly (as you suggested). Problem is, you can't see it clearly from storyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do in this way. You have two ViewController, one is DefaultViewController, the other one is LoginViewController. Check login or not, and set rootViewController as the viewController you want show.

BTW, when you want to store users info like id and password, use keychain not NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I'm actually doing server requests with user/pass and storing boolean in loggedIn key of NSUserDefaults.. Password doesn't get saved anywhere in app :) Concerning those controllers.. It is good idea, but is it possible to implement it also visually in storyboard? (I have no problem with writing code, but some of my collegues preffer storyboards because they have limited knowledge of obj-c)